# why compiler can't deduce template argument in my code?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, pointer-to-member, visual-studio-2010

I'm using visual studio and I've tried every thing I could think of. but don't know why this piece of code generates error, this is my code:

```
template <class A,class B> B returnArgtype(void (A::*)(B)) {return *new B;}

struct test
{
    void function(int);
    decltype(returnArgtype(&test::function)) x;
};
```

and it generates this error :

```
error C2784: 'A returnArgtype(void (__thiscall A::* )(B))' : could not deduce template argument for 'void (__thiscall A::* )(B)' from 'void (int)'
```

and I'm wondering it doesn't generate that error when parameter x is initializing inside a function, something like this:

```
struct test
{
    void function(int)
    {
        decltype(returnArgtype(&test::function)) x;
    }
};
```

Comment: Does the first one work if you say `&test::function`?

Comment: no, that was my copy-pasting error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same bug I linked to on your other question (please upvote it to make it more likely MS will spend time fixing it):

[C++ compiler loses member-ness of pointer-to-member-function during template deduction, causes ICE](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/678295)

Then, look at [@Ise Wistera's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569716/temple-of-template-c/6572669#6572669) which is much simpler and probably doesn't cause this problem.

---

Microsoft updated the bug report to say they've figured out a fix.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (GCC 4.6, `-std=c++0x`):

```
template <class A, class B> B returnArgtype(void (A::*)(B));

struct test
{
  void function(int);
  decltype(returnArgtype(&test::function)) x;
};
```

Comment: It seems it only has problem on visual studio, I've tested that code on GCC myself and I didn't encounter any problems. I was looking for some answer to fix that in Visual studio.