# c++ template parameter type inference

Tags: c++, templates, type-inference, inferred-type

I have such a template in C++

```
template<typename T, T* P> struct Ptr {};
```

so I can use it as such:

```
const int i = 0;
Ptr<int, &i> ptr;
```

or

```
Ptr<decltype(i), &i> ptr;
```

But I don't want to specify the type `int` or identity `i` twice, I want to use just

```
Ptr<&i> ptr;
```

and let the compiler figure out the `int` type part by itself.

How can I declare my template to do that ?

I've read this question but the answer is using macros, that's not nice: 
[template of template c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569716/template-of-template-c)

can I do this by just template without macros ? I'm using Visual C++ 2013.

Comment: Maybe if you could explain what is it exacly you are tring to achive?

Comment: @petric: it seemed clear to me: the goal is to support `Ptr<&i> ptr;` and make the `int` type completely implicit rather than having to type it out.

Comment: I guess it's not possible; You at least need to specify `int` when declaring `Ptr<int> ptr;`, then you want to give your object a parameter, so that you need to specify it again: `Ptr<int, &i> ptr;` or something like `std::shared_ptr`: `Ptr<int> ptr(&i);`

Comment: @JohnZwinck if he would show the way he uses this type inside the struct it is possible to find a way to omit the T or the T* and get his way...

Comment: @JohnZwinck I think petric was more asking what OP's goal is, ie *why* does he want to be able to do this. The problem in question seems like a strange one to want to solve.

Comment: @petric My goal is kinda similiar to the question I linked in the Q, the Ptr struct is used to access (get/set) some variable in a generic manner.

Comment: oh crap I just noticed I linked to the wrong SO questing in the Q, the one I read was actually this, will edit the Q also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569716/template-of-template-c

Comment: @petric more specifically, the Ptr struct can have members like `T get() { return *P; }` and `set(T value) { *P = value; }` etc.

Comment: This is exactly [N3601 Implicit template parameter](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3601.html), which is not yet supported

Comment: @PiotrS. oh YES you are right! glad to know someone in the commitee is at least thinking about it. But it looks like I can't mark your comment as the answer. :-(

Comment: You can use an ugly macro until N3601 is accepted. `#define PTR(t) Ptr<decltype(t),&t>` or something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the template<typename T, T t> idiom?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983802/what-is-the-templatetypename-t-t-t-idiom)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**UPDATE**

[c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) introduced "[P0127R2 Declaring non-type template parameters with auto](http://wg21.link/p0127r2)", allowing to declare a non-type template parameter(s) with `auto` as a placeholder for the actual type:

```
template <auto P> struct Ptr {};
```

That is, `P` is a non-type template parameter. Its type can be inferred with `decltype(P)`.

`auto` in a template parameter list is subject to well-known deduction and partial ordering rules. In your case, the type can be constrained to accept pointers only:

```
template <auto* P> struct Ptr {};
```

Note that the syntax utilizing `auto` is sufficient even for more detailed inspection, e.g.:

```
template <typename F>
struct FunctionBase;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct FunctionBase<R(*)(Args...)> {};

template <auto F>
struct Function : FunctionBase<decltype(F)> {};
```

It's also possible to use the inferred type as a contraint for other template parameters:

```
template <auto I, decltype(I)... Is>
struct List {};
```

---

**Old answer**

Since you are asking about a pure class template-based solution without the help of macro definitions then the answer is simple: as for now (Dec 2014, [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14)) it is *not possible*.

This issue has been already identified by the WG21 C++ Standard Committee as a need and there are several proposals to let templates automatically infer the type of non-type template arguments.

The closest is [N3601 Implicit template parameters](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3601.html):

> #### Implicit template parameters
>
> The purpose of this example is to eliminate the need for the redundant `template<typename T, T t>` idiom. This idiom is widely used, with over 100k hits on Google.
>
> The goal is to be able to replace a template declaration like `template<typename T, T t> struct C;` with another declaration so that we can instantatiate the template like `C<&X::f>` instead of having to say `C<decltype(&X::f), &X::f>`.
>
> The basic idea is to be able to say `template<using typename T, T t> struct C {/* ... */};` to indicate that `T` should be deduced. To describe in more detail, we consider some extended examples of template classes and functions.
>
> [...]
>
> The key idea is that passing the type of the second template parameter is redundant information because it can be inferred using ordinary type deduction from the second type parameter. With that in mind, we propose that prefacing a template parameter with using indicates that it should not be passed explicitly as a template argument but instead will be deduced from subsequent non-type template arguments. This immediately allows us to improve the usability of `describe_field` as follows.
>
> ```
> template<using typename T, T t> struct describe_field { /* ... */ };
> /* ... */
> cout << describe_field<&A::f>::name;   // OK. T is void(A::*)(int)
> cout << describe_field<&A::g>::arity;  // OK. T is double(A::*)(size_t)
> ```

A similar proposal is the one included in [N3405 Template Tidbits](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3405.html):

> #### T for two
>
> The motivating example is a putative reflection type trait giving properties of a class member.
>
> ```
> struct A {
>   void f(int i);
>   double g(size_t s);
> };
> /* ... */
> cout << describe<&A::f>::name;   // Prints "f"
> cout << describe<&A::g>::arity;  // prints 1
> ```
>
> The question is *"what should the declaration of describe look like?"* Since it takes a non-type template parameter, we need to specify the type of the parameter using the familiar (100k hits on Google) `“template<class T, T t>”` idiom
>
> ```
> template<typename T, T t> struct describe;
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> Our key idea is that passing the type of the second template parameter is (nearly always) redundant information because it can be inferred using ordinary type deduction from the second type parameter. With that in mind, we propose allowing `describe` to be declared as follows.
>
> ```
> template<typename T t> struct describe;
> /* ... */
> cout << describe<&A::f>::name;   // OK. T is void(A::*)(int)
> cout << describe<&A::g>::arity;  // OK. T is double(A::*)(size_t)
> ```

The current status of both proposals can be tracked under [EWG issue 9](http://cplusplus.github.io/EWG/ewg-active.html#9).

There are some other [discussions](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!searchin/std-proposals/auto$20templates/std-proposals/-ohiCmXXllk/Pd4GCqQzabcJ) proposing alternative syntax with `auto`:

```
template <auto T> struct describe;
```

Comment: In C++, you can parametrize your template parameters which will be deducted while being deducted.