# Design pattern for exception-safe trampolines

Tags: c++, c++11, trampolines

This question follows from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27821106/435129).  However, the previous question was worded so badly (wrongly in fact) that it was suggested I ask again from scratch.

I have a table of C-function pointers.

Some C code (let us call it lib-X) has a basic building block (let's call it a X-object). Each X-object can invoke functions on this table.

These table functions generally have different signatures (see typedefs [here](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Include/object.h)), although it is possible for several functions to share the same signature. There are about 100 of these functions in the table.

In C++ I have an associated Final:Base class for each X-object.

And I want to forward these calls to the X-object's corresponding C++ Final instance, but I want to enclose this within try/catch, as the C++ consumer may provide a buggy Final.

So I have a C++ Base class that has a virtual function for each entry on the table.

I then have a C++ Final class (possibly many; Final1 Final2 Final3 etc) that derives from the base class.

So now I just need to write a handler that

1. Gets the first 'self' parameter (which will always be a pointer to the X-object that invoked the function)
2. Retrieves the associated C++ base class instance.
3. Within a try catch block, invokes the corresponding virtual function, forwarding all the remaining parameters through,
4. ... which will actually invoke the override in Final.

It's a bit like trying to understand the plot for Inception. lib-X is in fact the Python runtime, although I'm trying to keep things general.

The thing is there are dozens of these functions, and this makes for some very messy and unmaintainable C++ code -- if I have to manually write a trampoline function for each one, looking like:

```
extern "C" PyObject *call_handler( PyObject *self, PyObject *args, PyObject *kw )
{
    try
    {
        PythonExtensionBase *p = getPythonExtensionBase( self );
        if( kw != NULL )
            return new_reference_to( p->call( Object(args), :Object(kw) ) );
        else
            return new_reference_to( p->call( Object(args), Object() ) );
    }
    catch( Py::Exception & )
    {
        return NULL; // indicate error
    }
}
```

(source [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/cxx/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/CXX/Src/Python3/cxx_extensions.cxx))

I'm trying to come up with a compact design that allows this exception-safe trampolining.

My current progress is [REMOVED, see answer below]

Comment: You have not called `trampoline.enable_f2();` in your code sample linked at the bottom ("EDIT").

Comment: @dyp, ARGH! Thanks! (buggy code removed now)

Comment: Could be wrong, but wouldn't the NVI (non-virtual interface) idiom solve this? Base class has public non-virtual methods that forward to protected helpers. The non-virtual methods can then see to your try/catch code quite conveniently.

Answer (score 3):

something like this?

```
template<typename RET, class ...Args> // <-- one trap for each f in Base that gets enabled!
RET trap( RET (Base::*f)(Args...), void* self, Args&&...args )
{
    try {
        auto base = reinterpret_cast<Base*>(self);
        return (base->*f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    catch (...) {
        return (RET)0;
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I invoke that?  `void enable_f1() { table.fp_1 = &trap<int, &Base::func_1>; }` ?

Comment: It's a function - call it with the pointer to member function, the pointer to base and any other parameters.

Answer (score 3):

I got it working thanks to [Piotr's answer to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27822086/435129), from which I have lifted the core machinery (so please upvote his answer).

Coliru [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8cbf4ca2f5e9752)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class Base {
public:
    virtual int   func_1( int a )        { std::cout << "Base::func_1" << std::endl; return a; }
    virtual float func_2( int a, int b ) { std::cout << "Base::func_2" << std::endl; return a+b; }
    virtual float func_3( char a )       { std::cout << "Base::func_3" << std::endl; return (float)a; }
};

class Final : public Base {
public:
    int   func_1( int a )           override { std::cout << "Final::func_1" << std::endl; return a+1000; }
  //float func_2( int a, int b )    override { std::cout << "Final::func_2" << std::endl; return a*b; }
    float func_3( char a )          override { std::cout << "Final::func_3" << std::endl; throw 666; }
};

Base* get_base(void* s) {
    return reinterpret_cast<Base*>(s);
}

template <typename T, T t>
struct trap;

template <typename R, typename... Args, R(Base::*t)(Args...)>
struct trap<R(Base::*)(Args...), t>
{    
    static R 
    call(void* s, Args... args)
    {
        std::cout << "trap:" << typeid(t).name() << std::endl;
        try
        {
            return (get_base(s)->*t)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            std::cout << "CAUGHT" << std::endl;
            return std::is_integral<R>::value ? static_cast<R>(-42) : static_cast<R>(-3.14); 
        }
    }
};


#define TRAP(f)  & trap<decltype(&f), &f>::call

class Trampoline 
{
    using F1 = auto ( void* self, int a )         -> int;
    using F2 = auto ( void* self, int a, int b )  -> float;
    using F3 = auto ( void* self, char a )        -> float;

    struct Table {
        F1* fp_1;
        F2* fp_2;
        F3* fp_3;
    };
public:
    Table* table = new Table();

    void enable_f1() { table->fp_1 = TRAP( Base::func_1 ); }
    void enable_f2() { table->fp_2 = TRAP( Base::func_2 ); }
    void enable_f3() { table->fp_3 = TRAP( Base::func_3 ); }
};

int main()
{
    Trampoline trampoline{};

    trampoline.enable_f1();
    trampoline.enable_f2(); 
    trampoline.enable_f3(); 

    Final final{};

    void* base_as_pvoid = (void*)static_cast<Base*>(&final);

    // test
    int u    = trampoline.table->fp_1( base_as_pvoid, 2 );     std::cout << u << std::endl; // expect: 1002   (enabled and Final provides override)
    float v  = trampoline.table->fp_2( base_as_pvoid, 3, 5 );  std::cout << v << std::endl; // expect: 8      (enabled but no override)
    float w  = trampoline.table->fp_3( base_as_pvoid, 'x' );   std::cout << w << std::endl; // expect: -3.14  (enabled and Final provides override, which throws!)
}
```

Comment: Instead of generating the function pointer in the calls of those member functions, you could as well generate a statically filled table and copy the entries on demand. Something like `constexpr static Table base_table = { TRAP(Base::func1), TRAP(Base::func2), TRAP(Base::func3) };`