# Perfect-forward non-T arguments while converting T-s

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

*(This question follows from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27830944/435129))*

I am trying to adapt a trampoline function that is currently just passing through a variable number of arguments.

I would like to have it convert any argument `PyObject* pyob` to `Object{pyob}`, but forward all other arguments through.

So `(void* self, int, PyObject*, float)` -> `(int, Object, float)`

In that example, the first `self` argument is stripped away. This always happens. Out of the remaining arguments, one of them is of type `PyObject*`, and hence requires conversion to Object.

Here is the function:

```
template <typename T, T t>
struct trap;

template <typename R, typename... Args, R(Base::*t)(Args...)>
struct trap<R(Base::*)(Args...), t>
{    
    static R 
    call(void* s, Args... args)
    {
        std::cout << "trap:" << typeid(t).name() << std::endl;
        try
        {
            return (get_base(s)->*t)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            std::cout << "CAUGHT" << std::endl;
            return std::is_integral<R>::value ? static_cast<R>(-42) : static_cast<R>(-3.14); 
        }
    }
};
```

It appears not to be forwarding arguments. I think it is making a copy of each argument. I've tried:

```
call(void* s, Args&&... args)
```

But that just generates compiler errors.

The complete test case is [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd0af10c4abecf1c)

How can I fix the function to perfect-forward all arguments apart from those of type `PyObject*`, which it should convert?

Comment: Thread it through a function overloaded on `PyObject` and with the other overload being a no-op template that just forwards the argument back out?

Comment: @Pi I'm not sure what is your concern here, having a non-explicit constructor will allow you to do this conversion implicitly. Also, generating the `call` function from given member function pointer already gives you a parameter of type `Object`, so why do you expect `PyObject*` to be passed in? Does that mean you want also to replace any occurrence of `Object` to `PyObject*` in `call` function signature, and then convert it to `Object` ?

Comment: @PiotrS., You are ahead of me -- Yes! I didn't realise it when I wrote the question but that's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *It appears not to be forwarding arguments*

You can't *perfectly-forward* arguments of a function which is not a template, or which is invoked through a pointer to a function, like you do. *Perfect-forwarding* involves a *template argument deduction*, which doesn't take place when you invoke a function through a pointer - that pointer points to a *concrete instantiation* of a function template.

The `std::forward<Args>(args)` expression is there to possibly utilize a *move-constructor* to copy-initialize the parameters of the target function from those arguments of `call` that are passed *by value* (or by a hard-coded rvalue reference), or let them be bound by an rvalue reference - you won't need any more those instances, you are free to *move-from* them, saving at least one copy operation. (It could be as simple as `static_cast<Args&&>(args)...`, because it's just a reference collapsing).

---

> *I would like to have it convert any argument `PyObject* pyob` to `Object{pyob}`, but forward all other arguments through. How can I fix the function to perfect-forward all arguments apart from those of type `PyObject*`, which it should convert?*

```
#include <utility>

template <typename T, typename U>
T&& forward_convert(U&& u)
{
    return std::forward<T>(std::forward<U>(u));
}

template <typename T>
Object forward_convert(PyObject* a)
{
    return Object{a};
}

// ...

return (get_base(s)->*t)(forward_convert<Args>(args)...);
```

---

To replace any occurrence of `Object` with `PyObject*` while creating the signature of `call` function, and only then conditionally forward or convert the arguments, you should do what follows:

```
template <typename T>
struct replace { using type = T; };

template <>
struct replace<Object> { using type = PyObject*; };

// you may probably want some more cv-ref specializations:
//template <>
//struct replace<Object&> { using type = PyObject*; };  

template <typename T, T t>
struct trap;

template <typename R, typename... Args, R(Base::*t)(Args...)>
struct trap<R(Base::*)(Args...), t>
{    
    static R 
    call(void* s, typename replace<Args>::type... args)
    {
        try
        {
            return (get_base(s)->*t)(forward_convert<typename replace<Args>::type>(args)...);
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            return std::is_integral<R>::value ? static_cast<R>(-42) : static_cast<R>(-3.14); 
        }
    }
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ba7fa62fe91af698)

Comment: Thankyou! Could you explain why such complexity is necessary for forward_convert? It looks as though it may be handling some edge case I don't need to worry about. (I have < 100 functions I need to wrap (typedefs [here](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Include/object.h)), and they have obvious signatures. So I don't need to make a reusable component. Could I get away with something simpler?

Comment: @Pi I made it much simpler

Comment: This looks much nicer. I think it can be simplified [even further](http://ideone.com/uur8Ad) ...

Comment: @Pi no, because your version doesn't attempt to **conditionally** move from arguments that are passed by value or an rvalue reference

Comment: Sorry to say I can't get my head around the double forwarding or the use of 2 template parameters for the general forward_convert, and the unused T parameter in the specialisation. Is there any chance you could include some explanation in your answer?

Comment: @Pi the unused template parameter `T`: 1. forces you to specify it in both overloads, 2. makes the second overload a template as well, so that the compiler can pick it when you call it like `forward_convert<Object>(PyObject*)`. the double forward is just because you wanted a simpler version: the forwarding reference produces an exact match

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68473/discussion-between-p-i-and-piotr-s).

Comment: and btw. `T` itself is needed for making the `static_cast<T&&>` (aka. `std::forward`)

Answer (score 3):

You have to change call to (Note that I introduce `Ts` in addition to `Args`).

```
template <typename ... Ts>
static R 
call(void* s, Ts&&... args)
{
    std::cout << "trap:" << typeid(t).name() << std::endl;
    try
    {
        return (get_base(s)->*t)(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "CAUGHT" << std::endl;
        return std::is_integral<R>::value ? static_cast<R>(-42) : static_cast<R>(-3.14); 
    }
}
```