# Selective forwarding function

Tags: c++, c++11, forwarding, perfect-forwarding

The task is to create a single-argument function that forwards all types apart from one (Foo), which it converts (to Bar).

(Let us assume there exists a conversion from Foo to Bar).

Here is the usage scenario:

```
template<typename Args...>
void f( Args... args )
{
    g( process<Args>(args)... );
}
```

*(I've tried to extract/simplify it from the original context [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27843095/435129). -- if I've made a mistake, please someone tell me!)*

Here are two possible implementations:

```
template<typename T>
T&& process(T&& t) { 
    return std::forward<T>(t); 
}

Bar process(Foo x) { 
    return Bar{x}; 
}
```

And...

```
template <typename T, typename U>
T&& process(U&& u) {
    return std::forward<T>(std::forward<U>(u));
}
 
template <typename T>
Bar process(Foo x) {
    return Bar{x};
}
```

I have it on good authority ([here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68473/discussion-between-p-i-and-piotr-s)) that the second one is preferable.

However, I can't understand the given explanation. I think this is delving into some of the darkest corners of C++.

I think I'm missing machinery necessary to understand what's going on.  Could someone explain in detail?  If it is too much digging, could anyone recommend a resource for learning the necessary prerequisite concepts?

*EDIT: I would like to add that in my particular case the function signature is going to match one of the typedef-s on [this page](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Include/object.h). That is to say, every argument is going to be either `PyObject*` (with `PyObject` being an ordinary C struct) or some basic C type like `const char*`, `int`, `float`. So my guess is that the lightweight implementation may be most appropriate (I'm not a fan of over-generalising). But I am really interested in acquiring the right mindset to solve such problems as these.*

Comment: Those examples are missing the context in which the process function is invoked - always with an explicit type template argument (at least that was the idea to turn non-lvalue-references into xvalues). You can get away with your version, but it will always call copy ctor while initializing parameters of the target function

Comment: I agree with version 1 being somehow "dirty", because its an overload of non templated function over a templated one and they only differ by return type. But for version 2 I can not see any sense. You would always have to specify the first template parameter anyway, because the compiler cannot deduce it in a usage context.

Comment: @PiotrS., I've edited to provide a context (I think it matches my actual use case). Thanks to your invaluable help these last couple of days, I now have a working solution ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27866483/435129)). This is the last component I'm chewing on because I don't like incorporating code I don't understand.

Comment: Your first solution does not work: the 2nd function will not be called by `process<Arg>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sense a minor misconception in your understanding of the use case you are facing.

First of all, this is a function template:

```
struct A
{
    template <typename... Args>
    void f(Args... args)
    {
    }
};
```

And this is not a function template:

```
template <typename... Args>
struct A
{
    void f(Args... args)
    {
    }
};
```

In the former definition (with a function template) the argument type deduction takes place. In the latter, there is no type deduction.

You aren't using a function template. You're using a non-template member function from a class template, and for this particular member function its signature is fixed.

By defining your `trap` class like below:

```
template <typename T, T t>
struct trap;

template <typename R, typename... Args, R(Base::*t)(Args...)>
struct trap<R(Base::*)(Args...), t>
{    
    static R call(Args... args);
};
```

and referring to its member function like below:

```
&trap<decltype(&Base::target), &Base::target>::call;
```

you end up with a pointer to a static non-template `call` function with a fixed signature, identical to the signature of the `target` function.

Now, that `call` function serves as an intermediate invoker. You will be calling the `call` function, and that function will call the `target` member function, passing its own arguments to initialize `target`'s parameters, say:

```
template <typename R, typename... Args, R(Base::*t)(Args...)>
struct trap<R(Base::*)(Args...), t>
{    
    static R call(Args... args)
    {
        return (get_base()->*t)(args...);
    }
};
```

Suppose the `target` function used to instantiate the `trap` class template is defined as follows:

```
struct Base
{
    int target(Noisy& a, Noisy b);
};
```

By instantiating the `trap` class you end up with the following `call` function:

```
// what the compiler *sees*
static int call(Noisy& a, Noisy b)
{
    return get_base()->target(a, b);
}
```

Luckily, `a` is passed *by reference*, it is just forwarded and bound by the same kind of reference in the `target`'s parameter. Unfortunately, this doesn't hold for the `b` object - no matter if the `Noisy` class is movable or not, you're making multiple copies of the `b` instance, since that one is passed *by value*:

- the first one: when the `call` function is invoked itself from an external context.
- the second one: to copy `b` instance when calling the `target` function from the body of `call`.

[**DEMO 1**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43dbb8d4dfb66e69)

This is somewhat inefficient: you could have saved at least one copy-constructor call, turning it into a move-constructor call if only you could turn the `b` instance into *an xvalue*:

```
static int call(Noisy& a, Noisy b)
{
    return get_base()->target(a, std::move(b));
    //                           ~~~~~~~~~~~^
}
```

Now it would call a move constructor instead for the second parameter.

So far so good, but that was done manually (`std::move` added knowing that it's safe to apply the move semantics). Now, the question is, how could the same functionality be applied when operating on a *parameter pack*?:

```
return get_base()->target(std::move(args)...); // WRONG!
```

You can't apply `std::move` call to each and every argument within the parameter pack. This would probably cause compiler errors if applied equally to all arguments.

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5c46e6b1125ef5e)

Fortunately, even though `Args...` is not a *forwarding-reference*, the `std::forward` helper function can be used instead. That is, depending on what the `<T>` type is in `std::forward<T>` (an lvalue reference or a non-lvalue-reference) the `std::forward` will behave differently:

- for lvalue references (e.g. if `T` is `Noisy&`): the value category of the expression remains an lvalue (i.e. `Noisy&`).
- for non-lvalue-references  (e.g. if `T` is `Noisy&&` or a plain `Noisy`): the value category of the expression becomes an xvalue (i.e. `Noisy&&`).

Having that said, by defining the `target` function like below:

```
static R call(Args... args)
{
    return (get_base()->*t)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

you end up with:

```
static int call(Noisy& a, Noisy b)
{
    // what the compiler *sees*
    return get_base()->target(std::forward<Noisy&>(a), std::forward<Noisy>(b)); 
}
```

turning the value category of the expression involving `b` into an xvalue of `b`, which is `Noisy&&`. This lets the compiler pick the move constructor to initialize the second parameter of the `target` function, leaving `a` intact.

[**DEMO 3**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf08192fbd0c97b1) *(compare the output with DEMO 1)*

Basically, this is what the `std::forward` is for. Usually, `std::forward` is used with a *forwarding-reference*, where `T` holds the type deduced according to the rules of type deduction for forwarding references. Note that it always requires from you to pass over the `<T>` part explicitly, since it will apply a different behavior depending on that type (not depending on the value category of its argument). Without the explicit type template argument `<T>`, `std::forward` would always deduce lvalue references for arguments referred to through their names (like when expanding the parameter pack).

Now, you wanted to *additionally* convert some of the arguments from one type to another, while forwarding all others. If you don't care about the trick with `std::forward`ing arguments from the parameter pack, and it's fine to always call a copy-constructor, then your version **is OK**:

```
template <typename T>           // transparent function
T&& process(T&& t) { 
    return std::forward<T>(t);
}

Bar process(Foo x) {            // overload for specific type of arguments
    return Bar{x}; 
}

//...
get_base()->target(process(args)...);
```

[**DEMO 4**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/20742e89ad4120e0)

However, if you want to avoid the copy of that `Noisy` argument in the demo, you need to somehow combine `std::forward` call with the `process` call, **and** pass over the `Args` types, so that `std::forward` could apply proper behavior (turning into xvalues or not doing anything). I just gave you a simple example of how this could be implemented:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
T&& process(U&& u) {
    return std::forward<T>(std::forward<U>(u));
}

template <typename T>
Bar process(Foo x) {
    return Bar{x};
}

//...
get_base()->target(process<Args>(args)...);
```

But this is just one of the options. It can be simplified, rewritten, or reordered, so that `std::forward` is called before you call the `process` function (your version):

```
get_base()->target(process(std::forward<Args>(args))...);
```

[**DEMO 5**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8206e63030472c3a) *(compare the output with DEMO 4)*

And it will work fine as well (that is, with your version). So the point is, the additional `std::forward` is just to optimize your code a little, and the [**provided idea**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4955696bafeff7fb) was just one of the possible implementations of that functionality (as you can see, it brings about the same effect).

Answer (score 0):

Would not be the first part of Version 2 sufficient? only:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
T&& process(U&& u) {
    return std::forward<T>(std::forward<U>(u));
}
```

Given a usage case with an existing conversion (constructor for "Bar" from "Foo"), like:

```
struct Foo {
    int x;
};
struct Bar {
    int y;
    Bar(Foo f) {
        y = f.x;
    }
};
int main() {

    auto b = process<Bar>(Foo()); // b will become a "Bar"
    auto i = process<int>(1.5f);
}
```

You are forced to specify the first template parameter (the type to convert to) anyway because the compiler cannot deduce it. So it knows what type you expect and will construct a temporary object of type "Bar" because there is a constructor.

Comment: Question was poorly worded at first.  Question has been clarified, and your answer is (unfortunately) wrong.