# Deduce arguments of function given as template parameter in C++03

Tags: templates, c++03

I have the following code, which works well (http://ideone.com/cAS6qQ):

```
  int inc( const int& x) {
      return x+1;
  }

template< typename R, typename A, R fun( const A&)>
  struct From {
      void call() {
          cout << fun( 1);
      };
  };

...
    From< int, int, inc> f;  //I want to change it to more simple From< inc> f;
    f.call(); //returns 2
...
```

I'm trying to simplify my code, so I can construct objects of *From* class like this:

```
...
   From< inc> f;
   f.call( 1); //returns 2
...
```

I think it can be done somehow, since template parameters *R* and *A* are known from the function argument and return type. I can't put a single function as a parameter, because in my code it can take any type.

PS> I'm using C++03, so no cool features available for me.

Comment: [Not possible](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27372492/3953764), neither in C++14, probably it will be possible in C++1z

Comment: As Piotr comments, it's "in the works". If you are limited to C++03 there's not much that can be done unless your compiler supports something like `__typeof__`. Having that, or a C++11-onwards compiler, you can reduce the problem to `From<A_MACRO(inc)>` which at least simplifies the calling site to one argument.