# Deduce return and parameter types of function pointer passed as non-type template argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, non-type

I know that it is possible for the compiler to infer types for function pointers if said pointers are passed into my template function as arguments, but I want to pass mine as a non-type template argument and support *an arbitrary number and types of arguments*.

In spirit, what I want to do is this:

```
template <Ret (*Fun)(Args...), typename Ret, typename... Args>
Ret do_something_exciting(Args&&... args)
{
    // exciting things go here
    return Fun(std::forwards<Args>(args)...);
}

[...]

int some_arbitrary_function(double x, double y);

[...]

do_something_exciting<&some_arbitrary_function>(3.14, 9.82);
```

This obviously fails due to `Fun` being declared *before* `Ret` and `Args`, but if I were to declare `Fun` *after* `Ret` and `Args`, I could not use type deduction in the first place.

Am I attempting the impossible or can this be made to work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27372492/3953764

Comment: #define do_something_exciting(x) (x)

Comment: why do you want to pass as non-type argument? how is this better than `do_something_exciting(&some_arbitrary_function,3.14, 9.82);`?

Comment: @m.s. because I don't just want the wrapper function to call the intended function, I want a pointer to a function that will, when called, call my intended function as well as whatever the wrapper does, as in `int (*wrapped_funptr)(double, double) = &do_something_exciting<&some_arbitrary_function>;` – and to get ahead of the question why I want to do *that*: to see if it can be done mainly :)