# Is it possible to place function pointer in template parameter ahead of dependent type?

Tags: templates, c++11

I have a template that has a function pointer as it's 2nd parameter and a type that the function pointer is dependent on as it's first.

i.e.

```
template <typename P, typename void(*fn)(P)>
auto function(P) -> otherType<P, fn>;
```

I want to make it so that I can just specify the function pointer in the template list without having to specify the dependent type as that type *should somehow* be able to be inferred from the function pointer that I specify (or *maybe* even the parameter list, but I think that it probably is too far down the line).

My first thought was to defer the conversion to a template parameter value, by passing a template typename and then convert to a value after the fact though template metaprogramming wizardry.

i.e.

```
template <typename F, typename P>
auto function(P) -> [[ something here to get otherType<P, fn> if F was a function pointer ]]
```

However, I'm not sure how I can do this.  Any ideas?

## Edit

What I'm trying to accomplish here is to make a helper function that will generate a class object.  So, given what was said by StenSoft, this is what I've come up with.  Unfortunately it doesn't work with a failure inside the `main()` function where it cannot match to the correct function due to deduction failure:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<typename T, typename F>
struct wrapper_fntor
{
  T m_t;
  F m_f;
  wrapper_fntor(T t, F f) : m_t(t), m_f(f) {}
  void invoke() { m_f(m_t); }
};

template<typename T, void(*fn)(T)>
struct wrapper_fn
{
  T m_t;
  wrapper_fn(T t) : m_t(t) {}
  void invoke() { fn(m_t); }
};

template <typename T>
struct Wrapper;

template <typename Ret, typename P>
struct Wrapper<Ret(P)>
{
    template <Ret(*fn)(P)>
    static Ret function(P p)
    {
        return fn(std::forward<P>(p));
    }
    template <Ret(*fn)(P)>
    static P get_param_type(P);

    typedef decltype(get_param_type<Ret(P)>()) param_t;
};

template<typename F>
wrapper_fn<typename Wrapper<F>::param_t, &Wrapper<F>::function> make_wrapper(typename Wrapper<F>::param_t param)
{
  return wrapper_fn<typename Wrapper<F>::param_t, &Wrapper<F>::function>(param);
}

template<typename F>
wrapper_fntor<typename Wrapper<F>::param_t, F> make_wrapper(typename Wrapper<F>::param_t param, F fntor)
{
  return wrapper_fntor<typename Wrapper<F>::param_t, F>(param, fntor);
}


void function(int value)
{
    std::cout << "function called " << value << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    auto x = make_wrapper<function>(3);
    x.invoke();
}
```

<kbd>[demo](http://cpp.sh/4ev6)</kbd>

Comment: [c++ template parameter type inference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27372492/3953764)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: Thanks.  That is unfortunately the answer I was looking for. I.e. that it can't be done as of yet. :-(

Comment: There are few problems: `get_param_t` expects function pointer but you provide it function type in definition of `param_t`. Instead of `decltype(get_param_type<Ret(P)>())`, simply use `P`. `Wrapper` expects function type but you provide it function pointer. Use `Wrapper<decltype(F)>`. `Wrapper<F>::function` is a template, you need to specify its parameter: `Wrapper<decltype(F)>::function<F>`. And most importantly, it's impossible to declare `make_wrapper` in the way you want. That's why I use macro, not template method.

Answer (score 1):

For a similar problem I have used a templated function inside a templated wrapper class and a macro (this actually works with any parameters and return type):

```
template <typename T>
struct Wrapper;

template <typename Ret, typename... Params>
struct Wrapper<Ret(Params...)>
{
    template <Ret(*fn)(Params...)>
    static Ret function(Params... params)
    {
        return fn(std::forward<Params>(params)...);
    }
};

#define FUNCTION(fn) \
    Wrapper<decltype(fn)>::function<fn>
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's just too early in the mornings but I don't get it. Maybe give an example of its usage?

Comment: @Adrian To use it, just use the macro: `FUNCTION(theFunctionYouWantToPassToTemplate)`. It will return the appropriate `function` instance with filled template parameters (`Ret`, `Params...` and `fn`) that you can use for `otherType`. In this example, it returns a function that can be used to call `fn` (`FUNCTION(theFunction)(param1, param2, param3)`) so it is not much useful but you can easily change that to return something else.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not getting it.  I've updated my question in hopes that you can understand what I'm trying to accomplish.