# C++ non-type template template to function pointer/ref

Tags: c++, templates

Is something like this possible in C++11?  I'd like to pass in as a non-type template parameter a templatized function pointer/ref:

```
template <template <typename ... TRest> void (*request_suffix)(ATCommander&, TRest...)>
struct command_helper
{
    template <class ...TArgs>
    static void request(ATCommander& atc, TArgs...args)
    {
        command_base::prefix(atc);
        request_suffix(atc, args...);
    }
};
```

Specifically, the usage of request_suffix?  If so, is it possible also to dump the TArgs stuff?

I plan to then do something like:

```
// dummy example code, but very closely representative of the kind
// of thing we'll be doing
void specific_request_suffix(ATCommander& atc, const char* p1, int p2)
{
    cout << p1;
    cout << p2;
}

typedef command_helper<specific_request_suffix> command;

command::request(atc, "test param1", 7); // or similar
```

It's important that by the time command::request is issued, specific reference of specific_request_suffix should not be required.  Also, I am in an embedded environment so std::function is not necessarily available

Comment: There ain't no such thing as a non-type template parameter. You could have a class template with a single (non-template) static method instead.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik please refer to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters

Comment: I meant non-type template template parameter (the kind you try to make `request_suffix`) - there is indeed no such thing. You can pass a function pointer as a template parameter, but you can't pass a whole family of them. You can however pass a class (as a type parameter) that could have a member function template; or a class template (as a template template parameter) that could have a member function. Either of these achieve a goal of passing a family of functions to a template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `decltype` to infer types. It looks like a hack but surprisingly it works. See the implementation below:

```
void specific_request_suffix(ATCommander& atc, const char* p1, int p2)
{
    cout << p1;
    cout << p2;
}

template<typename T, T *t, typename... Args>
    struct command_helper
    {
        static T *func_ptr;
        static void Request(ATCommander &cmd, Args... args)
        {
            func_ptr(cmd, args...);
        }
    };

template<typename T, T *t, typename... Args>
    T *command_helper<T, t, Args...>::func_ptr = t;

template<typename T, T *t, typename... Args>
    command_helper<T, t, Args...> infer_command_helper(void(*f)(ATCommander&, Args...)) {}

template<typename T, T *t>
    struct command_type
    {
        using type = decltype(infer_command_helper<T, t>(t));
    };

using command = command_type<decltype(specific_request_suffix), specific_request_suffix>::type;

void Task()
{
    ATCommander cmd = 5;
    command::Request(cmd, "h", 10);
    cout << endl;
}
```

Note that the function name has to be used twice in the command type `using` declaration. I don't know how to avoid it :(

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27372492/c-template-parameter-type-inference) answer says that it's not possible to infer type from non-type template parameter:

> Since you are asking about a pure class template-based solution
>   without the help of macro definitions then the answer is simple: as
>   for now (Dec 2014, C++14) it is not possible.
>
> This issue has been already identified by the WG21 C++ Standard
>   Committee as a need and there are several proposals to let templates
>   automatically infer the type of non-type template arguments.

Since we require to get the function type from the function pointer to simplify the command declaration, I am inclined to conclude that it's not possible until next language standards.

**Previous attempt**

This was my first attempt, but it didn't satisfy all the requirements. Leave it here in case it's useful to somebody.

```
template <typename... Rest>
struct command_helper
{
    using TFunc = std::function<void(ATCommander&, Rest...)>;

    static void request(ATCommander &cmd, TFunc func, Rest... rest)
    {
        func(cmd, rest...);
        cout << "Hello in template " << endl;
    }
};
```

Now you can use it as below:

```
using ATCommander = int;

auto f=[](ATCommander& cmd, int version, double d)
{
    cout << "In lambda " << cmd << " version " << version << " d= " << d;
};

ATCommander cmd = 5;
command_helper<int, double>::request(cmd, f, 1, 0.5);
```

Comment: Clever, but as you predicted I don't think it covers my use case.  I've updated my original post, and I will experiment with your solution

Comment: What type is `specific_request_suffix` in your example? What type can it be?

Comment: Let me know what you think about the `decltype` solution.

Comment: Gonna try it out, it certainly is a solution but a little more verbose than I was hoping for .  I'm gonna hold out for a magic bullet, but if none arrives this will be the accepted answer

Comment: I updated the answer with a link to another question and a quote. It does not seem possible to simplify the command type declaration further :(

Comment: Yeah, it seems C++17 'auto' can help in this situation, but for C++11 (and appears C++14) we're kinda stuck